# Which noun should I make the verb agree with in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement

> One set of events in Lord of the Flies that shows how William Golding is a pessimist is/are the murders of Piggy and Simon and the attempted murder of Ralph.

Don't know whether to use "is" or "are." Both ways sound odd to me.

Comment: What's the subject? Isn't it *one set*?

Comment: Subject is one set.

Comment: And when have you ever seen one of anything take a plural verb?

Comment: I just don't think that "is the murders" sounds correct, but I guess it is grammatically correct. Forgive me I've never encountered something like this before.

Comment: A verb agrees with its subject. Nothing else matters.

Comment: The subject is "set of events", which is singular.  So use *"is"*.  But if it's any consolation, many native speakers might also get this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

*is* is correct. The subject is *set*, which is singular.

That said, the sentence is complicated, and could confuse readers. Rewording it might improve readability.